# Asynchronous threads

Tags: c, asynchronous

I have two functions in C, that will be called by c++ threads (one thread per function). I want to block one, when the other is running and vice-versa. How can I solve this?

Here the resume:

```
int adin_mem_read(SP16 *buf, int sampnum, int client_id){

//(.....)
//lock writing_buffer
memcpy(&buf[real_size], stream_buffer_[client_id].data_ + stream_buffer_[client_id].p_read, stream_buffer_[client_id].p_write - stream_buffer_[client_id].p_read);
//unlock writing_buffer
//(....)
}
```

And:

```
int writing_bufer(struct Stream_Bufer * buffers, const char *data, int nbytes, int end_stream, int begin_stream) {

//(...)
//lock adin_mem_read()
memcpy(buffers->data_ + buffers->p_write, data, nbytes);
buffers->p_write += nbytes;
//(...)
//unlock adin_mem_read()

}
```

Comment: How are you creating these threads?  That library should have synchronization facilities included (locks, muteness, semaphores, monitors, whatever).

Comment: Semaphores? Locks? Condition variables? There are many ways to synchronize threads. But why? If you "pause" a thread while the other is running, why do you need threads in the first place?

Comment: I seems strange to have just one thread to run at the time... are you sure you need threads? seems that a single threaded app could suffice here...

Comment: The `memcpy` of the first routine is in a "infinit loop" with `sleep()` and condition variables (at this moment), to read data while it arrives. I want to remove this sleep to some more efficient. Because `adin_mem_read()` only returns when all the data has passed. In the mean process it will do some signal processing, whit the data that arrives

Comment: If you are using C++ threads, you should use whatever API C++ provides to synchronize this. This is likely not possible with plain C.